# How to correctly authenticate with MongoDB when using Repositories in JAVA Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb

I am trying to get Data from a mongoDB with a repository. But when I call the "find" methods, java throws a MongoQueryException and tells me, that find requires authentication. I want to configure my application over a XML file and application.yml

My Product Class

```
@Document
public class Product{

    @Id
    @Getter @Setter
    private String _id;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String name;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String brand;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String line;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String classification;
}
```

My Repository

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends MongoRepository<Product, String> {

    public List<Product> findByBrand( String brand );
    public List<Product> findByBrandLike( String brand );    
    public List<Product> findByName( String name );
    public List<Product> findByNameLike( String name )  
    public List<Product> findByLine( String line );    
    public List<Product> findByLineLike( String line );    
    public List<Product> findByClassification( String classification );    
    public List<Product> findByClassificationLike( String classification );
}
```

My Configuration

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo https://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <mongo:repositories base-package="de.myproject.mongo.repositories"/>
    <mongo:mongo-client id="mongoClient" host="${my.mongodb.host}" port="${my.mongodb.port}"/>
    <mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" mongo-ref="mongoClient"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    ...
</beans>
```

My application.yml

```
my:
  mongodb:
    host: mongodb
    password: myPassword
    port: 27017
    username: myUser

    productdb: myDB # where to save product data
    product_col: product # where to put product content
    err_log: log # where  to put url's that did not work
```

This is the errorstack I get:

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'command find requires authentication' on server mongodb:27017; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'command find requires authentication' on server mongodb:27017
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:138)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2783)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2688)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2431)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ExecutableFindOperationSupport$ExecutableFindSupport.doFind(ExecutableFindOperationSupport.java:214)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ExecutableFindOperationSupport$ExecutableFindSupport.all(ExecutableFindOperationSupport.java:157)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.lambda$getExecution$1(AbstractMongoQuery.java:115)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:99)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.findByBrandLike(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.findByBrandLike(Unknown Source)
at de.myproject.spiders.ContentSpider$2.process(ContentSpider.java:179)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:715)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:638)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:248)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.process(Splitter.java:129)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:76)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:117)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:76)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:117)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:76)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:117)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:76)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.doService(CamelServlet.java:213)
at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:79)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'command find requires authentication' on server mongodb:27017
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:706)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:695)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:462)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:406)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:695)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:179)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:132)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2671)
    ... 150 more
```

I tried adding the authentication and database settings to the application.yml, but that did not work for me. If you need any more information, just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following properties to mongo-client and db-factory

```
<mongo:mongo-client id="mongoClient" credentials="${username}:${password}@${authenticationDatabase}" />
<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" mongo-ref="mongoClient" dbname="${databasename}"/>
```

**authenticationDatabase** is the database where the user is defined

**databasename** is your product database

Comment: it seems to have worked. i'm not getting the authentication error anymore. my followup problem now is, that methods like findAll() return an empty list. but thank you for your help. now I am a bit closer to the solution for my problems

Comment: Do you have data in your mongo database ? and if there is then in which collection ?

Comment: there are around 4400 entries in the Database. they are in the collection {databasename}.product. Is there something else, i need to add?

Comment: try counting the number of documents in the collection with mongotemplate.count(query, collectionName)

Comment: ok, so i tried the to count the documents like you said and i am getting 4409 documents. that's the exact count of documents, my mongo has in that collection